# Удалить запятые в localstorage после определенного символа

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Подскажите, в массив product_filter_arr циклом добавляю товары (product):

```
var products = product_filter_arr.push(product);
```

Получается вот такой массив

```
<div class="product">
<span class="title">Название</span>
</div>,
<div class="product">
<span class="title">Название</span>
</div>,
<div class="product">
<span class="title">Название</span>
</div>
```

Потом просто добавляю в блок, все нужные товары, и на запятые грубо говорю наплевать.

```
$("#product__yesfilter").html(product_filter_arr);
```

Сейчас нужно это все записать в localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('products', product_filter_arr);
```

Но появилось проблема с запятыми...
Вот так вывожу:

```
var localProd = localStorage.getItem('products');
$("#product__yesfilter").html(localProd);
```

И получаю в верстке запятые...
Пробовал сделать так:

```
var localProd = localStorage.getItem('products').replace('</div>,', '</div>');
```

Не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраняйте не массив строку и будите на выходе тоже получать строку, я думаю это должно помочь

```
localStorage.setItem('products', product_filter_arr.join(''));
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.getItem(...).join is not a function

Comment: Можете скинуть полный листинг кода, желательно на сандбокс ?

Comment: это не массив, это и так строка, поэтому join не сработал

Comment: Вы сохраняйте в локалстораж массив и выводите как текст, поэтому у вас запятые, я обновил свой пост